# Visual studio 2010 checking out the solution everytime I open it

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Everytime I open the solution in visual studio 2010, it is checking out the .sln file. I am using TFS for version control.

When I compare the solution file most of cases I don't find any difference, but in some cases I do see difference in 'PORT' number.

How do I avoid that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen when your solution file has a `GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals)` section defined. From the sound of your question, the 'PORT' number is likely defined within such a section. This problem has been tracked in [this Microsoft Connect post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/573538/visual-studio-2010-with-tfs-2010-always-checks-out-the-solution-file-when-opening), and is apparently still an issue in Visual Studio 11 Beta according to the most recent commenter. Microsoft's suggested workaround for this issue is to remove the entire section between `GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals)` and `EndGlobalSection`. This may not be useful in your scenario, however, depending on the usage of that 'PORT' value. If it is required by some plugin or external utility, for instance, it may be re-added or cause a failure of the supplied functionality.